# Errors while Backing up Maps in MineCraft PE for android?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I am going to be getting a new phone soon and want to backup my world to transfer over but when I navigate to `games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/...` and try to copy the contents, only a couple files transfer before an error pops up

ok so now I tried to do it to replicate the error (an error I've seen like 20 times) and it worked... :(

UPDATE:
So I was able to get the error again, is just says unspecified error while coping files, and it seems to be the db folder that has the issue

Comment: So, what's the question here? It seems you solved the problem by yourself...

Comment: well I'm curious why I got errors in the first place, it wouldn't copy the files from my phone over USB to the PC

Comment: If you want to know why, post the erroro log first (or a screenshot is useful too)

Comment: Do you get the error message while transferring other files, or just Minecraft worlds? Does it occur when your phone is on/off/locked/unlocked? **What does the error message say?**

Comment: "Error copying file to folder: unspecified error" 

I was able to get it to come back up, seems to be a bunch of microsoft access locking files that stop the transfer, if I don't try to copy them, other files will copy, but the access files stop the others from copying

Answer (score 1):

It does appear to be related to files being locked and may be related to recent worlds. I was able to fix the "unspecified error" when copying Minecraft worlds, with the following:

1. Install a file explorer program like ES File Explorer on the Kindle
2. In ES File Explorer, copy/paste the world folder in question to a different folder on the Kindle Fire itself, for example the Documents folder
3. Connect the Kindle Fire to the PC
4. Copy the world folder from the Documents folder instead of the Minecraft folder

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before and restarting the device (Kindle Fire for me) and then connecting it before unlocking the home screen and copying helps. I belive it's a file in use type error that doesn't let it be copied when it's in use as it's usually only on the world(s) I've most recently played.